# Julia and Bessel functions

Tags: julia, bessel-functions

I am interested in Julia and would like to understand a couple of things before I dive into it. I would like to have a look at a working code which calculates [this expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuUus.jpg).

In that expression everything is a constant but for the Bessel functions, of course. The number n is an integer and "e" is an eccentricity (ranging from 0. to, say, 0.999).

For a given value of n I would like to derive hc,n. E.g. if n=2, then hc,2.

No, I am not tricking you into coding for me.

I am used to working with shell scripts, bc, and plot with gnuplot. I would like to have something more flexible than all of this and this one would be a good example to start looking at julia. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't have to do with what the code will look like, but you should check out https://github.com/JuliaMath/Bessels.jl which is pure Julia implementations of the Bessel functions that are 2-10x faster than the Fortran code pretty much everyone else uses.

Answer (score 1):

For the best tutorial on doing equations/mathematics in Julia have a look at https://github.com/mossr/BeautifulAlgorithms.jl

This will give you an excellent overview along with the initial feelling of the language.